# can i get some android applications which can be automated using robotium

Tags: robotium

I need some android applications which can be automated using robotium.

Answer (score 2):

You can try these:

http://devblog.xing.com/qa/robotium-atxing/

http://bitbar.com/blog/54/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can use the notepad app:

http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the samples in the Android SDK package ? 
I used some samples imported into my workspace to play around with Robotium. 
You can import any sample project by going in Eclipse :

File > Import > Existing project into workspace > Choose the path (sdk\samples\android-?\sampleProject)

Or you can do it like this : 
File > New > Other > Android Sample Project > Select Android version > Select sample

I personally played with Robotium using the NotePad sample from Android 2.1 samples